# Fastest way to get creation and last modification times of a lot of files

Tags: linux, solaris, aix, ksh

Given

- a directory
- a sh pattern which yields a subset of files directly in this directory (like *.log)
- a sh pattern which can, given a filename,

what is the fastest way (in ksh) to obtain for each file filtered in by the pattern:

- its name
- the date and time of its last modification (i.e. text appended)
- the date and time where it was created (supposing it was created in the directory were it is when we access it)

Ideally, it would work on both:

- AIX 6100-04-03-1009
- Linux 2.6.18
- SunOS 5.10

Comment: Creation time doesn't exist in POSIX/SUS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Posix file system node typically has three time attributes:

- `atime` (access time)  -- when was the file last read
- `mtime` (modification time) -- when was it last written to.
- `ctime` (change time) -- when was its inode (metadata) changed.

The `ctime` attribute is frequently misunderstood as creation time, and sometimes it is, which tends to confuse people.

POSIX shells have no standard way of extracting these three attributes, and you will depend on the `ls` command.  `ls -l $file` by default shows modification time.

- `ls -lc  $file` shows `ctime`
- `ls -lu $file` shows `atime`

It is recommended to use `ls --time-style=full-iso` or another iso format for consistent output, if you are on a GNU/linux system.

In Perl and other scripting languages, it's easier to [`stat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stat.html) a file and access its attributes.  Perl even has the `-M`, `-A`, and `-C` operators that return `mtime`, `atime`, and `ctime` for a file system object.  Note the time offset, though.  Perl tends to report times relative to the process start time.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for not writing the awk/sed for you, but the `stat` command will provide accessed, modified, and changed times. It will glob for you. Im not sure if it works in AIX, I have no access to that presently.

Comment: "Changed" and "modified", are they not synonyms?

Comment: If the files permissions, ownership, gets changed, then that will update the ctime, but not the mtime.

Comment: And I just logged into AIX, im afraid `stat` wasnt there... sorry, im an AIX smitty noob.

Comment: "metadata change time"

Comment: "inode" change time.

Comment: If on AIX, check for istat instead.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a GNU extension, but GNU find has printf formats for all 3 times, excluding the "birth" time.  (That requires a Linux `statx` system call; current versions of  coreutils `stat` can get all 4 times).

```
find -printf '%a \t%c \t%t  \t%f\n'
```

will print all 3 times like

```
Tue Dec  8 07:49:12.3585942200 2020     Tue Dec  8 07:49:27.9582201460 2020     Tue Dec  8 07:49:27.9582201460 2020     ./foo.c
```

You can use `%A`k where k is a format specifier, same for ctime and mtime, to print in a different format.  See the [Linux man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)

https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1p/find/ doesn't mention `-printf` at all, so you might need `perl` or other non-POSIX tools.